# How to make a dragable items list in windows phone like home page tiles of phone

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I am working on a windows phone app. I want to make a list whose items are draggable anywhere horizontally or vertically. List items are of image types.

Basically I want this like windows phone main page that contains tiles. When we hold a tile for some time it popups and can be draggable to anywhere in page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at Blend Interaction behaviours. I did a sample a while back
http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/wp7-drag-drop-example/